# This script in Javascript executes action twice. I wonder why?

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop

This code is made in JavaScript to be run by Photoshop to do the following described below.

Here is the code of the script a developer wrote to me.
What this code does:

Load TITLE.txt content into > variable $workingLayer
1 check if such layer exists> if not execute action "NOTEXISTS" from the actions in Photoshop.

2 Action after doing some funny things ends up with creating a new layer with layer name "0".

3 Then the script should change the "0" into whatever is inside of the workingLayer variable loaded fromt TITLE.txt

If it exists:
1 change the layer name of layer "$workingLayer" into "0"

2 execute the action "EXISTS"

3  change the layer name back from "0" into "$workingLayer"

so I tested this after some kind gentleman here helped me fix some syntax errors.

The problem now is that the action executes the action "NOTEXISTS" twice

I wonder why... hmmm

Here is the entire code:

```
function somename(){
    #target photoshop
    
    var fileRef = "C:/Users/Dharmindar/OneDrive/Desktop/NAME.txt"
    var doc = open(fileRef);
    alert(doc);
}
// this function somename is supposably testing if the name.txt can be opened and it gives an alert 

// this is anther test function I guess to see how to get layers name or document name I am not sure what he did here

function testFunction() {
    var testName = app.activeDocument.name;
    var nameWithoutExt = testName.split(".")[0];
    nameWithoutExt = nameWithoutExt + ", " + app.activeDocument.layers[0].name;
    alert(nameWithoutExt);
}






   //here he lists files from folder desktop and then he loops and searches for a file named TITLE.txt. from there he reads the value that he puts into a layer workingLayer. Later he will execute function based on the fact if the layer exists or not.
function SomeOtherFunction() {
    //Choose the desired folder
    var currentFolder = new Folder('~/desktop/');

    //Get files from the selected folder
    var currentFiles = currentFolder.getFiles(); 
    var selectedFile;

    for (i = 0; i < currentFiles.length; i++) {
        if  (currentFiles[i] == "~/desktop/NAME.txt") {
          selectedFile = currentFiles[i];
        }
    }


 // here he reads the file he opens and equates it to working layer
        selectedFile.open("r");
        var workingLayer = selectedFile.read();
    
        alert(workingLayer);

    var layers = app.activeDocument.layers;
    //alert(layers);

    for (l = 0; l < layers.length; l++) {
        //alert(layers[l].name + " - " + str); 
        var currentLayer = layers[l].name;
         // here he conditions and says if the working layer is equal to the current layer name then execute action exists from custom made 1145Actionset and later he says else, if it does not exist the layer with equal name as working layer then execute action 

        if(currentLayer.name == workingLayer) {
            currentLayer.name = "0";
            ExecuteAction("EXISTS","1145ActionSet");
        } else {
            ExecuteAction("NOTEXISTS","1145ActionSet");
        }

        RenameLayer("0", workingLayer, layers);
    }
}


//here he created function rename layer which is supposed to change layer names after the action has been completed and why was this needed? well it was needed because photoshop actions can not work with variables so what he did he changes the layer name to "0" and then executes action always on layer "0" and then after that he changes the layer 0 back to workingLayer variable value that comes from that TITLE.txt and that is pretty much all there is to it and this weird thing gives me error exactly on the line 60 it says it expects ; 
functon RenameLayer(oldName, newName, layers) {
    for (var j=0;j < layers.length; j++) {
        if (layers[j].name == oldName ){
            layers[j].name = newName;
        }
    }
}


function ExecuteAction(actionName, actionSetName) {
    try {
        //TO DO IF THE LAYER DOESNOT EXISTS
        //Action set must be created first and the action should be in that.
        //The first parameter is the name of th action to be performed and the second parameter is the name of th ActionSet
        app.doAction(actionName,actionSetName);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}


SomeOtherFunction();
```

Comment: here it says "edited sacha " left to my name 
can osmeone tell me what exactly did Sascha edit? And who is sascha?

Comment: @NoobForJS `functon RenameLayer` is not a function. You've missed out the "i" it should be `function RenameLayer`

Comment: Without seeing the text  and the PSD files it's difficult to see what is going on. I'm guessing you are looping over all layers including the background - which is why the action is getting triggered twice. If that's the case, try `for (var l = 0; l < layers.length-1; l++)`